# Looping objects then deleting them

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a simple loop which iterates a bunch of objects and checks if they match a variable and if they do, I want to remove it from the that list.

But i don't know how to do it... this is the idea of what I am trying to do :

```
//my_objects is global (window.my_objects)

for(var i in my_objects){

   if(my_objects[i].value == 100){
       //remove it
    }

}
```

Is there any option besides creating an array for it ? I could only find `delete` which only deletes the property which means the object will still be itereated through my loop next time around.

This function is called every X seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the property from the object like this means that it won't be in the iteration next time:

```
for(var i in my_objects){
   if(my_objects[i].value == 100){
       delete my_objects[i];
    }
}
```

Note: this removes the object in question as a property on  `my_objects`.  If there is no other code with a reference to the now removed object, then it will be available for garbage collection and eventually freed.

Comment: I thought delete could only remove properties of objects not the actual object how ever?

Comment: `for(var i in my_objects)` iterates the properties of `my_object`.  If you don't want something to be iterated the next time, you just remove the property in question and `delete` is what does that.

Comment: Ah okay! I see! Thanks :) One question though will the browser auto remove it if the my_objects ends up as `Object{}`  or do i have to remove that too free up memory?

Comment: If `my_objects` has no remaining properties, it will just be an empty object and it won't be garbage collected, but one empty object is a tiny amount of memory so nothing to worry about.  If you really wanted to clear it out, you could just set `my_objects = null;`.